# CordovaCall plugin is not buliding on VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a Cordova app in Visual Studio 2015. It works OK, but after adding plugin CordovaCall (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-call) I cannot build a project. I am getting the following error:

```
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     Execution failed for task
> ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. WMMobileApp     1    Error      Run with
> --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. WMMobileApp     1    Error      FAILURE: Build
> failed with an exception. WMMobileApp     1    Error      Error code 1 for
> command: cmd with args:
> /s,/c,"D:\WorkMobile\MobileApp\WMMobileApp\platforms\android\gradlew
> cdvBuildDebug -b
> D:\WorkMobile\MobileApp\WMMobileApp\platforms\android\build.gradle
> -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true" WMMobileApp     1    Error      D:\WorkMobile\MobileApp\WMMobileApp\platforms\android\src\com\dmarc\cordovacall\CordovaCall.java:69:
> error: cannot find symbol WMMobileApp     1   
> Error     D:\WorkMobile\MobileApp\WMMobileApp\platforms\android\src\com\dmarc\cordovacall\CordovaCall.java:178:
> error: cannot find symbol WMMobileApp     1    Error      > Compilation failed;
> see the compiler error output for details.    WMMobileApp     1    Error      2
> errors    WMMobileApp     1    Error      * What went wrong:  WMMobileApp     1   
> Error     * Try:  WMMobileApp     1    Error       ^  WMMobileApp     1    Error      
> ^ WMMobileApp     1    Error       symbol: variable
> CAPABILITY_SELF_MANAGED   WMMobileApp     1    Error       symbol: variable
> CAPABILITY_SELF_MANAGED   WMMobileApp     1    Error       location: class
> PhoneAccount  WMMobileApp     1    Error       location: class
> PhoneAccount  WMMobileApp     1    Error      
> .setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_SELF_MANAGED)    WMMobileApp     1   
> Error     
> .setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_SELF_MANAGED)    WMMobileApp     1
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: what is the command you are using to build the app?

Comment: Just BUILD in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Its a plugin issue so the first step is to find the source for the plugin. In this case it looks like https://github.com/WebsiteBeaver/CordovaCall/issues/27 - have you tried the steps discussed there?